# Use ruby grpc client with self signed certificate

Tags: grpc, grpc-ruby

Trying to use ruby GRPC client to connect to a go GRPC server. The server uses TLS credentials with self signed certificates. I have trusted the certificate on my system (ubuntu 20.04) but still getting `Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED`

Only way this is working is by manually setting `GRPC::Core::ChannelCredentials.new(File.read(cert_path))` when initializing the client. Another workaround is setting `:this_channel_is_insecure`, but this only works if I remove TLS credentials in the server altogether (which I do not want).

Is there any way to get the GRPC client to work with the system certs?

I assume the gem is using [roots.pem](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/etc/roots.pem) and trying to override that using `GRPC::Core::ChannelCredentials.set_default_roots_pem` results in `Could not load any root certificate`.

Also, I have not found any parameter that would let me skip certificate verification.

Answer (score 1):

The default root location can be overridden using the `GRPC_DEFAULT_SSL_ROOTS_FILE_PATH` environment variable pointing to a file on the file system containing the roots. Setting `GRPC::Core::ChannelCredentials.new(File.read(cert_path))` also seems fine to me.

In Ruby, most likely the feature to skip cert verification in TLS is not supported. We have the corresponding feature supported in underlying core, but it might not be plumbed to Ruby yet(at least not that I am aware of). If you need that, feel free to open a feature request to in gRPC Github page.

Thank you!